# Having Issue with Log4j File Rotation

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

We just recently upgraded our tomcat from 7 to 9 after upgrading we are having issue with our log rotation. We are using default tomcat log file (tomcat.log).

Our Log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, INFO
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileLogger
log4j.appender.fileLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileLogger.File=tomcat.log
log4j.appender.fileLogger.MaxFileSize=10KB
log4j.appender.fileLogger.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

Issue we are facing is our log file does not rotate until we restart our tomcat and if the file rotate log stops printing in the log file until we restart tomcat server.

Comment: Is the backtick at the end log4j.appender.fileLogger.MaxBackupIndex=5` just a copy/paste error?

Comment: yes its a copy/paste error